Unicast UDP socket tx buffer fills awaiting ARP
I have an 'understanding' question but it does have a real-world case that I've simplified out. Consider this sample network (with simplified IPs):

From left to-right:

Three hosts S1-S3 (IPs , running three programs R1-R3 respectively; A switch with 3 VLANS and a trunk port connected to eth0 of a 4th host S4. All are Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but that's probably irrelevant.
S4 is running P1 that binds to three UDP sockets, one on each of three vlan interfaces on the respective networks of S1,2,3
P1 Sends unicast and multicast UDP messages to several ports on each of those sockets at rates of 10-100Hz. There is a netfilter OUTPUT chain gating these flows.

Each of the red areas represents something that might be 'down'. In all of these cases except one the UDP datagrams are immediately discarded:

Virtual interface V10 is link down; process R2 isn't running; or OUTPUT chain DROPs the flow - In each case the packets is either silently discarded by S2 or an error is reported back to the P1 and the packet dropped. All other mcast continues to flow.
In the case of S3, after removing the OUTPUT block, the tx buffer of the socket on v12 rapidly fills up with unicast packets bound for 12.1 and this blocks any further writes of both unicast and multicast.

In this state an strace on P1 might look like this (trimmed):
15:38:27 sendto(9, ... {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2347), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.1")}, 16) = 31674
15:38:27 sendto(9, ... {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2347), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.1")}, 16) = 31674
15:38:27 sendto(9, ... {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2347), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.1")}, 16) = 31674
15:38:27 sendto(9, ... {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2347), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.1")}, 16) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
15:38:30 sendto(9, ... {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2347), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.1")}, 16) = 31674
15:38:30 sendto(9, ... {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2347), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.1")}, 16) = 31674
15:38:30 sendto(9, ... {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2347), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.1")}, 16) = 31674
15:38:30 sendto(9, ... {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2347), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.1")}, 16) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)

And ss shows the problem:
State    Recv-Q  Send-Q   Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port  Process
UNCONN   0       148992   0.0.0.0:51047        0.0.0.0:*          users:(("task",pid=381888,fd=9))
     skmem:(r0,rb212992,t148992,tb131070,f0,w0,o0,bl0,d0)

So we have 4 * ~30kb writes to the (default 120kb) socket buffer with the 4th reporting EAGAIN when the buffer is full. The buffer is repeatedly filling while the OS is waiting for an ARP response from S3 that will never come.
Two questions off the back of all this:

UDP is unreliable by nature. Our application is quite happy that packets are otherwise discarded, so why would tx be queued this way while the kernel is trying to resolve ARP? (Consider the case where S3 might only be occasionally connected but other hosts on v12 might still be reachable.)
The buffer appears to be emptied (then rapidly filled with new writes) every 3 seconds. One of the results is that any multicast that makes it into that same tx queue comes out in little bursts rather than at the steady send rate. Sure we can open more send sockets, but where is this value set and is this behaviour tuneable in sysctl?



UDP is unreliable by nature. Our application is quite happy that packets are otherwise discarded, so why would tx be queued this way while the kernel is trying to resolve ARP? (Consider the case where S3 might only be occasionally connected but other hosts on v12 might still be reachable.)

Your application might be, but most other applications aren't very happy when packets are discarded. They do usually have timeouts and retransmissions, but those generally are much longer than it takes for an ARP query to succeed.
For example, if the kernel were to drop a TCP SYN (instead of queueing it) because it has to issue an ARP query for the gateway, it would take 3 seconds for the retransmission, versus ~0.003 seconds for the ARP response. The same goes for UDP-based DNS queries and most other protocols. (Not to mention the ones which don't have retransmission – Syslog over UDP does not, and would flat out lose most messages if they weren't frequent enough to keep the ARP cache entry alive.)

The buffer appears to be emptied (then rapidly filled with new writes) every 3 seconds. One of the results is that any multicast that makes it into that same tx queue comes out in little bursts rather than at the steady send rate. Sure we can open more send sockets, but where is this value set and is this behaviour tuneable in sysctl?

net.ipv4.neigh.*.unres_qlen_bytes seems to be the sysctl (as well as the deprecated .unres_qlen) that controls how much data can be queued for an unresolved neighbor.
The adjacent .mcast_solicit × .retrans_time_ms sysctls control how many times (and at what intervals) a multicast solicitation or broadcast ARP query will be retried before the neighbor entry enters the 'FAILED' state and all of its queued packets are dropped.
(Once that happens, the next packet will trigger a new series of neighbor discovery attempts while new packets get queued again, resulting in the 3-second cycle under default settings.)
If you're trying to find this within the Linux sources, grep for QUEUE_LEN_BYTES and specifically look for __neigh_event_send() in net/core/neighbour.c. It seems that the queues are attached to the same neighbor entries you see in ip [-s] neigh, though it doesn't show the per-neighbor queue size.

Thank you! I think I've been guilty of looking at this at the UDP level rather than IP. Of course ARP doesn't know or care that's resolving on behalf of a UDP or TCP flow and has to queue regardless. I was wondering if a 'rolling buffer' solution would be possible, but I see now that it isn't. In our case the block itself isn't a problem, but we'll need to improve our socket code to ensure that it doesn't block anything else behind it.

Just to confirm for future readers: Setting (eg) net.ipv4.neigh.v12.retrans_time_ms=500 and net.ipv4.neigh.v12.mcast_solicit=2 does indeed change the observed burst rate to 1Hz.
